# Browser extension for getting data from the next layer page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

let's say I have a page (twitch just for example), where I want to display the number of subscribers next to the streamer nickname:

[image]

This information is located on "the next" page after clicking the streamer tile:

[image]

There is no API, I can get this data only by accessing the tree:

[image]

**Is there any way to access this data from the next page and display on the previous?**

I want to use chrome and js, but any other solutions are accepted if they make it possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to write a script yourself, take a look at [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).

You would use js (vanilla or jQuery) to find all of the stream preview / streamer name elements on the page, and for each, use the [gm_xmlhttpRequest](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php?locale=en#api:GM_xmlhttpRequest) function to open the linked stream page. You should then be able to query the page returned by gm_xmlhttpRequest and find the element containing the watchers.

Comment: note that you could run into rate limits if you open too many sites at once. Also maybe the info is loaded dynamically via Ajax, so loading the html page might not be sufficient, in that case you might be better off scraping the data from some third party site or trying to find the internal api from twitch for this.